# vehicles: power supply controlled by ignition with clean power off

Tags: power, cars

I read a lot about this but I can't find a satisfying solution.

I want the Pi to automatically power on when I start the engine and 
to cleanly power off when I turn it off.

what I thought was to power the Pi from the vehicle battery using a 12v to 5v charger and to connect it to the cigarette lighter socket through a 12V DC DPDT relay, which shorts a pin configured for `dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown` when I turn the ignition off and shorts the RUN pin to resuscitate the Pi when I turn the it on. see image below:
[image]
the problem is that the Pi doesn't boot when I short the RUN pin but only when I reopen the circuit between the 2 pins.

solutions?

Comment: google `picopsu` ... https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=z2aQNlo9dbU

Comment: I've been using this without a single problem for over a year: https://mausberry-circuits.myshopify.com/collections/car-power-supply-switches/products/3a-car-supply-switch

Comment: I'm looking for something cheaper, I shouldn't be far away from the answer

Comment: maybe a NC relay between RUN and GND pins so that when the circuit is closed it opens immediately after could work?

Comment: @SoreHands does it cut the power to GPIO/USB too when the Pi is powered off?